# Avoiding Memory Leaks when passing pointers to functions

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Im reading up how to avoid memory leaks and to my understanding , a memory leak occurs if you lose anyway to refer to allocated memory (therefore you cant free it) but this example from Wikipedia confuses me

```
 #include <stdlib.h>

void function_which_allocates(void) {
    /* allocate an array of 45 floats */
    float *a = malloc(sizeof(float) * 45);

    /* additional code making use of 'a' */

    /* return to main, having forgotten to free the memory we malloc'd */
}

int main(void) {
    function_which_allocates();

    /* the pointer 'a' no longer exists, and therefore cannot be freed,
     but the memory is still allocated. a leak has occurred. */
}
```

My code is below, what Im doing is creating an array of structures called arrayOfStrucs that hold structures called CreatedStruct, then a LinkedList points to each instance of arrayOfStrucs.

Will I get memory leaks as I dont free memory I allocated in the same function ie CreateLinkedList ( i allocate arrayOfStructs but dont free it as I still need it to be pointed by a Linked List) To me im not creating any orphaned pointers as im always able to reference them at any time

```
   struct LinkedList *temp = head;
   CreatedStruct* StructPtr = &temp->arrayOfStruct[1];
   int* intPtr = StructPrt->data;
   printf("int data = %d\n", *intPtr);
```

With the code above I can print the value of arrayOfStruct ( so the only data member in CreatedStruct which is int* data) so dosent that mean it wont leak?
Does the Wiki example cause a leak because function_which_allocates(); didnt return a reference to the allocated memory, or is it because the allocation and freeing of the memory were in different functions ( different scopes)

```
int main(void)
{
    struct LinkedList *head =NULL;
    head = CreateLinkedList(head)
    printLinkedList(head)
    //Can this be done if I follow the correct way of freeing a linked list?
    FreeLinkedList(head)
}

LinkedList* CreateLinkedList( LinkedList* head)
{
    CreatedStruct* arrayOfStrucs; 
    //Allocated but will be freed in a separate function    
    arrayOfStructs= malloc(1 * sizeof(CreatedStruct));
    FillArrayOfStructs(arrayOfStructs); 
    head = FillLinkedList(head, arrayOfStrucs);
    return(head) 
 }


FillArrayOfStructs(CreatedStruct* arrayOfStructs) 
{
    arrayOfElements[1].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
    ptr = arrayOfElements[1].data;
    *ptr = 65;     
}


LinkedList* FillLinkedList(LinkedList* head, CreatedStruct* arrayOfStructs) 
{
    LinkedList* insertNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    insertNode->arrayOfStruct = (void*)arrayOfStructs;
    insertNode->next = head;
    return insertNode;         
}
```

**Summary**

Can memory leak be caused by not allocating and then freeing memory in the same function scope ( ie allocated in main, which main then passes the pointer to a seperate freeing function)

Comment: `LinkedList FillLinkedList()` <-- you're returning a pointer, not a `LinkedList`

Comment: Your example does not compile.

Comment: @EOF Its not really supposed to, im just trying to show what my structure is like and how pointers are being passed between functions

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem oops my bad, fixed

Comment: Every memory block obtained via `malloc` and friends that is not freed with the `free` function will yield in a memory leak and this is toally independent of scopes. Or in other words, you may allocate a memory block in some function and free it later in a totally different function; this is actually how `malloc` and `free` are used most of the time.

Comment: What's wrong with people on this site down-voting perfectly reasonable questions. It's clear that the OP has done some research and put a fair amount of effort into the question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz so If I malloc'd in main then passed the pointer into a function, that then that function passed it into another. As long as I have a way to reference it when I want to free it back in main ( double pointers maybe?) It wont be a leak?

Comment: @user2697817 I was afraid it wasn't to the point , that could be why

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thankyou so much :)  I dunno if you want to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Code still doesn't compile. Is it too much to ask for you to try compiling and running before posting? No. You spent much longer writing up your non-code.

Comment: @Seb Sorry I didnt realise a question like this needed code that could compile. It was more to show the structure and how the pointers are passed function to function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every memory block obtained via `malloc` and friends that is not freed with the `free` function will yield in a memory leak and this is toally independent of scopes.

In other words, you may allocate a memory block in some function and free it later in a totally different function; this is actually how `malloc` and `free` are used most of the time.

**Example** (just for illustration purposes, not necessarily good programming practice)

```
char *Foo()
{
   ...
   return malloc(...);
}

void Bar()
{
  char *p = Foo(); 
  ...
  free(p);   // freeing the pointer that has been allocated in Foo
}
```

The Wiki example causes a leak because once the function has been executed, the a pointer doesn't exist any more because it is a *local variable* that exists only during the execution time of the function.

But the memory block itself that has been allocated and that was pointed by `a` is still allocated and now there is no more way to free it because the only pointer (`a`) that pointed to it is gone.

Comment: Just for the sake of future students, when people jump from a cliff *most of the time*, would you join them? Using `malloc` like that example goes against the grain of the standard library, where only the memory allocation functions allocate memory, and everything else won't. `malloc` is most useful for allocating dynamic sized objects.

Comment: @Seb as you can see this is just an illustration that serves no other purpose that illustrating what the OP was asking. BTW maybe the `...` argument to `malloc` in `Foo` _is_ some dynamically calculated size.

Comment: For the sake of others who may see this yes, all objects I was going to use malloc for were to be dynamically sized